# Syntax error when doing POSTGRES LIKE through Knex.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, knex.js

This is giving me a syntax error:

```
if (searchCode) {
  customerProducts = await customerProducts.andWhere(
    db.sequelize.knex.raw('customer.code LIKE '
      + `%${searchCode}%`)
    );
  }
}
```

The error looks like this:

```
{"message":"UnknownErrorMiddleware error: select \"CustomerProduct\".\"id\" as \"_id\", \"CustomerProduct\".\"last_delivered\" as \"_lastDelivered\", \"CustomerProduct\".\"margin\" as \"_margin\", \"CustomerProduct\".\"outlier\" as \"_outlier\", \"CustomerProduct\".\"growth\" as \"_growth\", \"CustomerProduct\".\"period\" as \"_period\", \"CustomerProduct\".\"price\" as \"_price\", \"CustomerProduct\".\"active\" as \"_active\", \"CustomerProduct\".\"customer_id\" as \"_customerId\", \"CustomerProduct\".\"product_id\" as \"_productId\", \"CustomerProduct\".\"modified\" as \"_modified\", \"CustomerProduct\".\"month_value\" as \"_monthValue\", \"customer\".\"id\" as \"_customer_id\", \"customer\".\"title\" as \"_customer_title\", \"customer\".\"code\" as \"_customer_code\" from \"customer_products\" as \"CustomerProduct\" inner join \"customers\" as \"customer\" on \"CustomerProduct\".\"customer_id\" = \"customer\".\"id\" where \"product_id\" = $1 and customer.code LIKE %ZOO1% - syntax error at or near \"%\"","level":"info"}
```

I think the problem is that there is no `''` around `%ZOO1%` but I don't know how I add this. How is it done and if this is not the problem, what is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add them like this `'%${searchCode}%'`. But the `searchCode` variable will be prone to sql injections.

Though, you should use the raw parameter binding feature

```
db.sequelize.knex.raw('customer.code LIKE ?', [`%${searchCode}%`])
```

https://knexjs.org/#Raw-Bindings